# high-dimensional index structures

Tags: algorithms, database, data-structures

I'm looking for information on searching (filtering) high-dimensional data. I'm not interested in nearest-neighbour search or clustering, but rather filtering/sorting by subset of dimensions - like in relational algebra.
Unfortunately my google-fu points me mostly towards spatial indexes or already mentioned nearest-neighbour.

- What's the proper name of the problem I'm interested in?
- Which index structures support this type of search?

(by high-dimensional I mean 100-1000 dimensions)

An example would be [compressed bitmap indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index#Compression)

Comment: Your problem is what Data Warehouses have to deal with. And quick google search shows there is nothing better than normal relational indexing.

Comment: Consider to add a more detailed example to your question for the kind of data and the use case you have in mind. In the current form, your question is IMHO very vague.

Comment: This paper may be helpful: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/redundant-bit-vectors-for-quickly-searching-high-dimensional-regions/